# Why does my wheat die immediately upon maturing, even when water is nearby?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've set up an outpost somewhat near an ocean monument, but out of range of where the guardians should bother me. I've tried farming some wheat, but it dies immediately upon maturing, so that when I harvest it I only get seeds. The farm is in a birch forest biome.

There's water within 4 blocks, at the same height as the wheat.

Using Minecraft Realms (Java edition) v1.19.4

Why would the wheat be dying/wilting immediately? Could the ocean monument be affecting it?

Comment: "Could the ocean monument be affecting it?" No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crops don't 'die' in Minecraft, they mature until their final state, where they will stay indefinitely (until broken). If broken before they reach their final state of maturity, crops will simply drop the seeds used to plant them, without giving any harvestable material.

As you're specifically attempting to harvest wheat - that crop has 8 distinct growth stages:

[image: wheat seed growth stages]
<sub>Courtesy of [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat_Seeds#Renders) -  ([CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/))</sub>

Only the final brown stage will drop [Wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat) (as well as 1-4 wheat seeds for continued propagation)